# How to write one regular expression to meet all cases and print specified variable

Tags: java, regex

I`d like to find some statements in a file.  And I need to print out element and sub element name.The statement like

```
set element elemName subElem sumElemName
```

If a element or sub element name includes one or more spaces, the entire string must be enclosed within double quotes. Double quotes are dispensable if there is no space in a element or sub element name. So following statements are valid.

```
set element "aaa bbb" subElem "ccc"
set element "aaa bbb" subElem ccc
set element "aaa" subElem "ccc"
```

I tried to write two expressions to meet some cases. But how to write one regular expression to meet all cases?

```
String regex = "^\\s*set\\s+element\\s+\"(.*)\"\\s+subElem\\s+\"(.*)\"\\s*$";
String regex = "^\\s*set\\s+element\\s+(?<!\")(\\S+)\\s+subElem\\s+(?<!\")(\\S+)\\s*$";
```

Comment: use a pipe `|` as `or` operator ?

Comment: `set element ("[a-zA-Z ]+"|[a-zA-Z]+) subElem ("[a-zA-Z ]+"|[a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: Pipe | is feasible. Maybe regex1|regex2|regex3 . But I think it is not a good solution. @Cid

Comment: Check Wiktor's answer, he always (often ?) knows what he is talking about when it comes to RegEx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may match substrings inside double quotes or a chunk of non-whitespace chars as the `elemNames`:

```
String regex = "^\\s*set\\s+element\\s+(\"[^\"]*\"|\\S+)\\s+subElem\\s+(\"[^\"]*\"|\\S+)\\s*$";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kklmjI/1/)

The `(\"[^\"]*\"|\S+)` pattern matches

- `\"[^\"]*\"` -  a `"`, then any 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"`
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.